# Unable to resolve target 'android 19' Working with API 21

Tags: android

I am working with API 21 because the latest libGDX is saying to get android 5.0(API 21) but this error keeps coming up. Should i ignore it or is their a fix. I tried getting android 4.4.2(API 19) but the android version is too outdated for libGDX.

Comment: Are you working on Eclipse or Android studio?

Comment: If you are getting this in Eclipse, this means that the `project.properties` file of the project that you are importing indicates that your target is `android-19`, and you do not have that SDK platform installed.

Comment: Yeah but how do i change the properties to android 5.o(API 21) I am on Eclipse